# Update docker environment path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, path, environment-variables

I have a `Dockerfile`, that is using a proprietary image, say it contains `FROM XXX` up top.  That image is based of `centos/python-38-centos7`.

At the end of this `Dockerfile`, I am updating the PATH with `ENV PATH=<my_path>:$PATH`, to have `my_path` in front.  Yet, when I start the container, using `docker-compose up --build`, there are a bunch of things in front of `my_path`. These are `/opt/rh/rh-nodejs14/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin:`, which seems to be from redhat?

I then decided to update the `docker-compose.yml` to have a section

```
environment:
  - PATH=<my_path>
```

Thinking PATH should just contain `my_path` and that alone, yet when I start the container it has `/opt/app-root/bin:<my_path>`.  Where/when is this extra path getting appended in front and how can I prevent this from happening?  I need `my_path` to be in front?

Comment: Does the image have an entrypoint wrapper script that's updating the environment variables before running the command?

Comment: Nope, ENTRYPOINT is /bin/bash